# Remove all the records from ets table having datestamp older than 10 seconds

Tags: erlang, elixir, data-cleaning, ets, cache-expiration

I have an `ets` set table in an elixir app. I need to clean-up records which have their updated_at field older than 10 seconds. Is there a way I can set expiry or do it manually without iterating over all the records? I match records based on the timestamps greater than given time.

example record:

```
key: key_1
record: %{id: key_1, updated_at: ~N[2018-12-19 10:08:47.803075]}
```

so far I have this code

```
def clean_stale(previous_key) do
  if previous_key == :"$end_of_table" do
    :ok
  else
    device = get(previous_key)
    next_key = :ets.next(__MODULE__, previous_key)
    if NaiveDateTime.diff(NaiveDateTime.utc_now, device.last_recorded_at) > 10 do
      remove(device.id)
    end
    clean_stale(next_key)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at an [advanced lookup](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/ets/#advanced-lookup)? i.e. derive a function that can do this comparison for you using `:ets.fun2ms/1`?

Comment: Thanks @matov. I think I got complete answer. yes I have. But as I am newbie didnt get much out of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you store the "updated at" time as an integer instead of as a `NaiveDateTime` struct, you can use a match spec.

For example, to get the current time as the number of seconds since the Unix epoch:

```
> DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now())
1545215338
```

You can do something like this:

```
iex(3)> :ets.new(:foo, [:public, :named_table])
:foo
iex(4)> :ets.insert(:foo, {:key1, DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now())})
true
iex(5)> :ets.insert(:foo, {:key2, DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now())})
true
iex(6)> :ets.tab2list(:foo)
[key2: 1545215144, key1: 1545215140]
iex(7)> :ets.select_delete(:foo, [{{:_, :"$1"}, [{:<, :"$1", 1545215144}], [true]}])
1
iex(8)> :ets.tab2list(:foo)
[key2: 1545215144]
```

In the call to [`ets:select_delete/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select_delete-2), I pass a [match specification](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html).  It consists of three parts:

- With `{:_, :"$1"}`, I perform a match on the records in the table.  In this example, I have a tuple with two elements.  I ignore the key with `:_`, and assign the timestamp to a match variable with `:"$1"`.
- With `[{:<, :"$1", 1545215144}]`, I specify that I only want to match records with a timestamp before this time.  In your case, you would calculate the time ten seconds in the past and put that value here.
- With `[true]`, I specify that I want to return `true` for matching records, which in the case of `select_delete` means "delete this record".

So after calling `select_delete`, only the second record remains in the table.

---

If the timestamp is inside a map, you can use `map_get` to access it and compare it:

```
:ets.select_delete(:foo, [{{:_, :"$1"},
                           [{:<, {:map_get, :updated_at, :"$1"}, 1545215339}],
                           [true]}])
```

Or (in Erlang/OTP 18.0 and later) match out the map value:

```
:ets.select_delete(:foo, [{{:_, #{updated_at: :"$1"}},
                           [{:<, :"$1", 1545215339}],
                           [true]}])
```

Comment: But in my case values are map. if value is just a timestamp then then its of no use in my case.

Comment: I updated the answer to get the timestamp from inside the map